# How to create and remove application shortcut into home screen?

Tags: android

I am creating a application shortcut. It's working fine. But i can't remove this shortcut. How to remove my application shortcut. In my home screen contains lot of application shortcut. How to remove that..
If it is possible please send information for how to remove application shortcut. Otherwise if it is not possible send Reason. Please reply your answers and comments are valuable me. Thanks.
My sample code is here...

```
    Button btnShortcut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateShortcut);
    btnShortcut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            Intent shortcutintent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            shortcutintent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
            shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
            Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
            shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MyActivity.class));
            sendBroadcast(shortcutintent);
        }
    });
```

My Android Manifest.xml code is here...

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

Comment: This is an undocumented and unsupported technique. This will not work on all home screens, and therefore will not work on all devices.

Comment: Thanks. But my emulator home screen contains more than one same short cut. What can i do? How to delete this.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
private void deleteShortCut(Context context) {

    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    shortcutIntent.setClassName("com.example.androidapp", "SampleIntent");
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    shortcutIntent.putExtra("someParameter", "HelloWorld");

    Intent removeIntent = new Intent();
    removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "ShortcutName");
    removeIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);

    removeIntent
            .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");       
    context.sendBroadcast(removeIntent);
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I checked this code. My application shortcut does not removed. Any other solutions.

Comment: As far as my research goes - no :/